# SVN show diff command confusion

Tags: svn, diff

Lets say Bob and Alice created one centralized svn repository. They both have a file in there called b.txt. Alice edited it and committed the copy first. Bob then edited/updated it and realized theres a conflict. He did svn diff command and got this:

```
This is going to be tricky.

Yes it will be.
It really will be.
+<<<<<<<.mine
+Bob tried to fix the file.
.I'm sure.
+========
+Alice is changing much.
+I'm sure of that
+ >>>>>>.r[5]
+:( What happened?

+Best of luck!

Best of luck!
+This is a mess.
```

What is in Alice's file? What is in Bob's file?

Alice's:

```
This is going to be tricky

Yes it will be.
It really will be.
Alice is changing much.
I'm sure of that
```

Bob's

```
This is going to be tricky

Yes it will be.
It really will be.
Bob tried to fix the file.
I'm sure
:( What happened?

Best of luck!
Best of luck!
This is a mess
```

Could someone tell me if I'm right?

What does the + mean? What does >>>>> mean? What does +==== mean? I don't know a resource for this

Comment: In a nutshell, the lines that start with `+` were added, those that start with `-` were removed, and the block between `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>` is a conflict (i.e. it was changed on both sides). The changes each side operated on the conflicting block are separated by the line `==========`. Also, at the end of the `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` markers, Subversion puts the numbers of the current revisions of the file on the two parties. The format is understood by the `patch` Unix tool.

Comment: Also read this: http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you can use [interactive conflict resolution tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve). It will help you resolve the conflicts without dealing with the conflict markers.

If you still want to resolve the conflict by hand, read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Manual conflict resolution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.byhand)